# Print the Section Number while Referencing Custom Command

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, counters, cleveref, setcounter

I have a custom command `\goal{}`

```
\newcounter{goalcounter}[section]
\newcommand\goal{\refstepcounter{goalcounter}{\textbf{Goal \thesection.\thegoalcounter}}}
```

Say in Section 1, I have `Our first \goal{} is to have fun`, which is rendered as `Our first Goal 1.1 is to have fun`. I want to reference this goal later, in another section as

```
Section 2
Recall that our Goal 1.1 in an earlier section was to have fun.
```

How do I do this?

In other words, how do I access the section number where the goal was created, to reference it later. Currently, I just label as `\goal{\label{goal11}}` and then later reference as `... our Goal 1.\cref{goal11} in ...`. Is there a better way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW, because `\goal` doesn't take any arguments, the only difference between `\goal` and `\goal{}` is that the `{}` makes the space happen afterward.  `\goal{\label{goal11}}` is the same as `\goal\label{goal11}`.

Comment: Right, I make it a habit to write `\goal{}` so that I don't introduce odd spacing errors sometimes, so `\goal{\label{goal11}}` just aesthetically fits better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `\label`, the latest stepped counter (via `\refstepcounter`) is stored. Specifically, `\the<cntr>` for the counter `<cntr>`. So, you need to define the section numbering as part of the goal number in this way:

```
\renewcommand{\thegoalcounter}{\thesection.\arabic{goalcounter}}
```

Comment: Awesome! this works for me. May I ask how is this implemented internally? In the sense I thought `\thegoalcounter` is an integer that is incremented every time by commands like `\refstepcounter`. But from your code it seems like even strings are getting correctly incremented.

Comment: @Ambar: `\thegoalcounter` is the *representation* of the `goalcounter` counter; that is, the visualisation that is printed. However, internally, `goalcounter` is just a single counter that has nothing to do with other counters (unless specified otherwise). So, I just changed how it looks: Prefix it with `\thesection.` and print the actual counter using the `\arabic` form (others include `\roman`, `\Roman`, `\alph` and `\Alph`, for example).